# Why am i getting this error? '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, append

I have tired lots of things to get around this error, but I am coming up dry. Anyone know why I keep getting this error?

```
myList =[n, weather, wind, other, avgscore]
    with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
        for s in myList:
            f.append(str(s) + '\n')
    print("Thank you, your data was logged")
```

Comment: `f.append()` Uh?  or you meant `f.write()`?

Comment: The error itself is self explanatory. You are trying to append to a `TextIoWrapper` object instead of a `list` object.

Comment: I tried f.write, but that kept overwriting the text already in the file.

Comment: @elliottbellamy see the edited answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `write()` instead of `append()`:

```
myList =['n', 'weather', 'wind', 'other', 'avgscore']
with open("list.txt", 'w') as f:
    for s in myList:
        f.write(str(s) + '\n')
print("Thank you, your data was logged")
```

Incase you want to append data to already written file and not overwrite it:

> You need to open the file in append mode, by setting "`a`" or "`ab`" as
>   the mode.

[docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

```
myList =['n2', 'weather2', 'wind2', 'other2', 'avgscore2']
with open("list.txt", 'a') as f:
    for s in myList:
        f.write(str(s) + '\n')
print("Thank you, your data was logged")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
n
weather
wind
other
avgscore
n2
weather2
wind2
other2
avgscore2
```

Comment: great ! @DirtyBit